# How to assign row 'j' to row 'i' which have different patterns using a loop in R?

Tags: r, loops, nested-loops

I am looking to put every row of 'df' into 'new_df'.

Here is my issue: the first row of 'df' and 'new_df' will be the same, but I need ROW 2 of 'df' to be put into ROW 12 of 'new_df', then ROW 3 of 'df' into ROW 23 of 'new_df', and so on... I'm skipping 11 ROWS of 'new_df' everytime for each ROW of 'df'.

Here is what I tried:

```
  for(i in seq(from = 1, to 3652, by = 11){ 
for(j in seq(from = 1, to =332, by =1)){
new_df[i,] <- df[j,] }}
```

Note: 'df' has 332 rows, 'new_df' will have 3652 rows (once I do the same process with my other 'df's).

This code seemed to skip the ROWS correctly in 'new_df', BUT, every ROW filled in 'new_df' was the last row of 'df'. (new_df[1,] was df[332,] , new_df[12,] was df[332,] , and so on...)

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Here is a visual example of what I'm trying to create (new_df):

```
df                           new_df
row1: 1 1 1                  row1: 1 1 1
row2: 2 2 2                  row2: NA NA NA
row3: 3 3 3                  ...
row4: 4 4 4                  row12: 2 2 2
                             ...
                             row23: 3 3 3
                             ...
                             row34: 4 4 4
```

Comment: You only need one loop `for(j in 1:332){i = 1 + 11 * (j - 1); ...}`. What is your next step in data processing as this is unusual.

Comment: Or better, assuming you already made new_df : `new_df[seq(from = 1, to 3652, by = 11), ] = df`

Comment: Thank you! I just tried your first comment and it worked perfectly, I used the same line with my other data get everything into new_df. I agree that this was pretty weird, it just happened to be the approach I thought up haha!

Comment: Actually in case anyone is around there is one more thing: is there a way to preserve the row names of 'df' after I put them in 'new_df'? I have 'new_df' fully populated now, but it would be great if they kept the same row names!

Comment: You should make a question with what you are actually trying to accomplish. As is, this seems like an xy problem.

Comment: Can you create a small reproducible example and show expected output for it? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269

Comment: The question was already answered, but I don't know how to close it! Since the answer was in a comment..